# Setup VPN with dynamic IP adressess

Tags: vpn, proxy, tor, anonymous

I'm trying to setup the dynamic IP solution on the Win server for some users. The IP addresses must be from US and the users can change the IP add frequently, but they have to got always different US IP add. The different IP address need only on the browsing, not whole connection.

Is there something useful to do it?

I've already try to use TOR or some VPN extension to browser, but there I still got same IP.

Thanks,

Comment: If you use TOR proxy, you must be doing something wrong... And: is it about the IP only, or also encryption and trackability?

Comment: just IP i need to changing. encryption and tractability doesn't matter.
And about TOR, I found out that I can change the IP, but I cannot to choose only from US IP's, not?

Comment: Is the user supposed to change the IP on will, or do you want this to be automatic. Also do you want each user to have a different IP at one given time?

Comment: "Is the user supposed to change the IP on will, or do you want this to be automatic"  -> it will be fine to do it  by some button, like change identity in TOR, so it should be manually, not necessary do it automatic

Comment: "each user to have a different IP at one given time?" -> I suppouse, if the user using own browser he is able to assign IP to browser session, via VPN